# xwd on Wayland: BadMatch

Tags: xorg, wayland

Does xwd not work on wayland?

I get:

```
$ xwd -root > l.xwd
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  86
  Current serial number in output stream:  86
```